# MongoDb Need help in finding highest value in database using aggregate

Tags: mongodb

I am working on a query to find the subject title, subject type, and credit value of subject with highest credit value. This is the query I have come up with:

```
 db.Subject.aggregate([{$match:{"subject.credit":{$max:true}},
{$project:{"subject.subTitle":1, "subject.type":1, "subject.credit":1,  _id: 0}}
]).pretty()
```

This doesn't seem to net anything.
and

```
db.Subject.aggregate([{$match:{"subject.credit":$max}},
$project:{"subject.subTitle":1, "subject.type":1, "subject.credit":1,  _id: 0}}
]).pretty()
```

This nets and error as shown below:

```
E QUERY    [js] ReferenceError: $max is not defined :
@(shell):1:32
```

Here is a part of the database that contains the highest credit value:

```
db.Subject.insert(
{ 
    "_id":ObjectId(),
    "subject":{ 
        "subCode":"CSCI321",
        "subTitle":"Final Year Project",
        "credit":6,
        "type":"Core",
        "assessments": [
                { "assessNum": 1,
                  "weight":30,
                  "assessType":"Presentation",
                  "description":"Prototype demonstration" },
                { "assignNum": 2,
                  "weight":70,
                  "assessType":"Implementation and Presentation",
                  "description":"Final product Presentation and assessment of product implementation by panel of project supervisors" }
            ]
  }
}
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A good strategy, if you don't have an index, is to collapse all documents and get one value:

```
const pipeline =  [
    {
        "$project" : {
            "subTitle" : "$subject.subTitle",
            "type" : "$subject.type",
            "credit" : "$subject.credit",
            "_id" : 0
        }
    },
    {
        "$sort" : {
            "credit" : -1
        }
    },
    {
        "$limit" : 1
    }
]
db.Subject.aggregate(pipeline)
```

**Query**

- `$project` We want only a subset of fields
- `$sort` to get the highest credit first.
- `$limit:1` to get only the highest.

Comment: was it really needed $group keyword?

Comment: what's your  simpler alternative? @dılosürücü

Comment: no  wrong for me, just ı asked ...$group keyword does  by group ,no problem

Comment: $group is necessary to find the max in _all_ documents, otherwise you find the max in an array from _one_ document

Comment: Your query does help me find the credit score with the highest value but I am required to list out all subject title, type and credit for the subjects with the highest credit value instead of just the highest credit value. If its not too much trouble for you, it is possible to craft another query?

Comment: does it work as you expect? @Frio_Penitencia

Comment: I was able to figure earlier myself, but your answer is way better. Thx for being so responsive!

Answer (score 0):

```
db.Subject.find({},{"subject.subTitle":1, "subject.type":1, "subject.credit":1,"_id":0}).sort({"subject.credit":-1})
```

just use this

Comment: I am only looking to list out the subject title, type and credit for the subjects with the highest credit value. After testing your query, it lists out the subjects with the highest credit value 1st but also lists out every other entry.

Comment: I am also only allowed to utilize aggregate.